# How to implement go grpc-go health check?

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I've been looking for a documentation and code samples of `grpc-go` health check.

Looking for issues in

- https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/448
- https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/2770

there is no clear answer I can re use to implement health checking in my program.

Answer (score 10):

I recommend you to have a look at this [Github project](https://github.com/apssouza22/grpc-production-go) to learn how to build a gRPC service prepared for production which includes the health check and much more.

Specific to health check you can check how it is done [here](https://github.com/apssouza22/grpc-production-go/blob/master/server/server.go#L85)

The library leverage from this more focused [project](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-health-probe)

If you don't want to use the lib you could implement the health check like this:

```
import (
    "google.golang.org/grpc/health"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/health/grpc_health_v1"
)
grpcServer := grpc.NewServer()
grpc_health_v1.RegisterHealthServer(grpcServer, health.NewServer())
```

Answer (score 4):

One of the links you posted has a link to this read me:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/health-checking.md

You now should implement that logic, and register that service in you set of services.

The readme suggest to manually register the services into the health check service, so you could pass the list of services as an argument to create the health check service.

I would recommend to define an interface for yours services, so the health check service could handle all of them in the same way:

```golang
type HealthMeter interface {
    GetHealth() mysample.HealthCheckResponse_ServingStatus
    WatchHealth() <- chan mysample.HealthCheckResponse_ServingStatus
}

// implement service "A" and "B" as both interfaces (gRPC server AND HealthMeter)

grpcServer := grpc.NewServer()
srvA := servers.NewServiceA()
srvB := servers.NewServiceB()
healthSrv := servers.NewHealthCheckServer(map[string]servers.HealthMeter{
    "serviceA": srvA,
    "serviceB": srvB,
})

mysample.RegisterServiceAServer(grpcServer, srvA)
mysample.RegisterServiceBServer(grpcServer, srvB)
mysample.RegisterHealthServer(grpcServer, healthSrv)
```

I hope it could help you.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to implement the health check [example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/examples/features/health/server/main.go) in the grpc package

```swift
/*
 *
 * Copyright 2020 gRPC authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 *
 */

// Binary server is an example server.
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "time"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    pb "google.golang.org/grpc/examples/features/proto/echo"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/health"
    healthgrpc "google.golang.org/grpc/health/grpc_health_v1"
    healthpb "google.golang.org/grpc/health/grpc_health_v1"
)

var (
    port  = flag.Int("port", 50051, "the port to serve on")
    sleep = flag.Duration("sleep", time.Second*5, "duration between changes in health")

    system = "" // empty string represents the health of the system
)

type echoServer struct {
    pb.UnimplementedEchoServer
}

func (e *echoServer) UnaryEcho(ctx context.Context, req *pb.EchoRequest) (*pb.EchoResponse, error) {
    return &pb.EchoResponse{
        Message: fmt.Sprintf("hello from localhost:%d", *port),
    }, nil
}

var _ pb.EchoServer = &echoServer{}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf(":%d", *port))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }

    s := grpc.NewServer()
    healthcheck := health.NewServer()
    healthgrpc.RegisterHealthServer(s, healthcheck)
    pb.RegisterEchoServer(s, &echoServer{})

    go func() {
        // asynchronously inspect dependencies and toggle serving status as needed
        next := healthpb.HealthCheckResponse_SERVING

        for {
            healthcheck.SetServingStatus(system, next)

            if next == healthpb.HealthCheckResponse_SERVING {
                next = healthpb.HealthCheckResponse_NOT_SERVING
            } else {
                next = healthpb.HealthCheckResponse_SERVING
            }

            time.Sleep(*sleep)
        }
    }()

    if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
    }
}
```